# XML keeps failing to validate, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: xml, schema

The XML code keeps failing to validate and i don't know why

I've looked up different answers and tried their suggestions but i am very new to XML so it didn't help me much

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
<pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512">
<pkg:xmlData>
    <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties" Target="docProps/app.xml"/>
        <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties" Target="docProps/core.xml"/>
        <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml"/>
    </Relationships>
</pkg:xmlData>
```

Schema code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2013 (http://www.altova.com) by Marina Kulakov (Internal Revenue Service) -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:ftc="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sfa="urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes:v2" xmlns:iso="urn:oecd:ties:isofatcatypes:v1" xmlns:stf="urn:oecd:ties:stf:v4" targetNamespace="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v2" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2.0">
    <xsd:import namespace="urn:oecd:ties:isofatcatypes:v1" schemaLocation="isofatcatypes_v1.1.xsd"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes:v2" schemaLocation="stffatcatypes_v2.0.xsd"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="urn:oecd:ties:stf:v4" schemaLocation="oecdtypes_v4.2.xsd"/>
    <!-- Document type indicators types -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="FatcaDocTypeIndic_EnumType">
    <xsd:annotation>
```

Once again I am very new to XML, I just expected the XML file to validate with no problems.

Comment: Both of your code samples are incomplete. Try to create a [mcve] in your question, because currently this question is unanswerable.

Comment: I forgot to add that the xml file was converted from word, i didn't create it and the schema was something i downloaded. I was told that the file needed to be sent in the form of xml, so i converted the word file however i couldn't update it due to it not being validated i guess

Comment: Missing closing tags on the xml code for `<pkg:package>` and `<pkg:part>`. Try adding `</pkg:part>` and `</pkg:package>` to the end of the code block.

Comment: If you got validation errors, tell us what they are! You might not understand them but it's very likely we will.

Comment: The target namespace of the schema seems to bear no relationship to the namespace used in your instance document.